# how to insert a calculated column letter in a formula excel

Tags: excel, char, row, multiple-columns

So I can calculate the column number based on a cell value as such

```
= CHAR(64+x)
```

with x the cell value based on e.g. user input

but now I want to add a value to another cell based on the calculated letter of the column from where to look for the value to add

say I **calculated** the letter B previously, based on e.g. user input

and I want to add the right value, namely the one in cell B3 (but this may change based on user input) to cell A1

```
=CHAR(64+2)3
```

does not work. Usually one uses =B3, but that is not possible here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `INDEX` with the column and row indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify Ben's comment, you could put an [Index formula](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-index-function/) in any cell on a worksheet and it would return the cell based on row/column parameters. While it's probably not good to specify the entire worksheet, you could do that by having a formula of:

```
=INDEX(1:1048576,5,8)
```

or with a more limited scope/range:

```
=INDEX(A:Z,5,8)
```

Both of these would return cell `H5` (row 5, column 8).

You could also use indirect (though Index is better).  Something like this based on your formula:

```
=INDIRECT(CHAR(64+2)&"5",TRUE)
```

Which results in....

```
=INDIRECT("B5",TRUE)
```

This would return cell `B5`